# Function precision and recall

Tags: function, precision, precision-recall

As a beginner in Machine Learning, I want to write a precision_recall function which computes the precision and recall. However, I have to use a third parameter of the function and I do not know how to do that. How do I fix the following code?

```
def precision_recall(y_true, y_pred, third):
    return precision_score(y_true, y_pred), recall_score(y_true, y_pred)
```

Thus, how should I change the code that a given class is extracted from the arrays?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score 

def precision_recall(y_true, y_pred, scalar):
    class_true = (y_true == scalar)
    class_pred = (y_pred == scalar)
    return precision_score(class_true, class_pred), recall_score(class_true, class_pred)

true = np.array(['red', 'green', 'blue', 'red', 'green'])
pred = np.array(['red', 'green', 'red', 'red', 'red'])

print(precision_recall(true, pred, 'red'))
print(precision_recall(true, pred, 'green'))
```

Output:

```
(0.5, 1.0)
(1.0, 0.5)
```